# working with jQuery promises

Tags: jquery, promise

I found some interesting posts about jQuery promises and I was trying this feature myself. I wrote the following code but I ran into a problem.

```
    var promises = [];
    objects.forEach(function(obj) {
        promises.push(
            $.ajax({
                url: 'myurl' + obj.id,
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            })
        )
    });

var everything = $.when.apply($,promises).done(function() {..})
```

So far so good.

After that I thought that I could use 'everything' to understand when the whole process was complete simply doing:

```
$.when(everything).done( function() { business logic })
```

but this last line gets immediately fired, so something is not working properly and I don't quite understand what. Could you give me a hand? Thanks

Comment: BTW, use `objects.map()`.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I have never used map() and I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks anyway for the contribution.

Comment: Your code looks fine and should work the way you expect it to (you don't actually even need `$.when(everything).done(`, you could use `everything.done(` directly.) If the requests are already done, calling .done and adding a callback will fire said callback immediately.

Comment: $.map would replace your foreach, `var promises = $.map(objects,function(obj){ return $.ajax(...);});`

Comment: Thanks for the comments @KevinB. I'm using .map() and it seems to work just fine. The main problem though stays there. 
I tried with `everything.done(directly)` but I have the same result. I obtain `undefined` because the flow brings me immediately there. If you say that it should work just fine then my problem has to be somewhere else..

Comment: What exactly is undefined?

Comment: Here's a sample that we can work with that simulates the ajax: http://jsfiddle.net/zqz6x/3/

Comment: Ok, this whole process is inside a function that returns my dataset.
Instead of the dots here: `$.when.apply($,promises).done(function() {..})`, I am actually initialising my dataset and here I am returning the dataset:
`$.when(everything).done( function() { return dataset })`

Comment: There's your problem. you can't return out of an asynchronous callback. you simply can't. Instead, you need to return the promise object from the function, then use the .done callback of the promise object to access the dataset. http://jsfiddle.net/zqz6x/4/

Comment: I did not save the fiddle, damn! But I think I understand. So, I return the promise object and from the _business_ function I invoke the .done callback on that promise. I'm going to give it a shot.

Comment: Ok, now my problem is clear:
I was constructing dynamically an object and I wanted to return it.
Within this .done() callback: `$.when.apply($,promises).done(function() {..})` I was even performing other ajax calls to fill my object but this whole thing does not work.
Now the question is: how do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `.done()` does not return a new promise, it just accepts some handlers and return's the same promise.  jQuery's promises are very broken (see "Note on jQuery's Promise implementation").  In almost all other promise libraries, `.done` behaves like `.then` but returns `undefined` and makes sure error messages aren't silenced.  In jQuery it's about as useful as a chocolate fire guard.

There is a `.then` method which acts as a transformation (a bit like `.map` for an array.

Considering this, you could do:

```
var promises = objects.map(function(obj) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'myurl' + obj.id,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
});

var everything = $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {..});

$.when(everything).done( function() { business logic });
```

It's also worth being aware that because `everything` is already a promise, `$.when(everything)` is just a pass through, so you can actually just write:

```
everything.done(function () { business logic })
```

### Note on jQuery's Promise implementation

It's worth noting that jQuery's promise implementation is pretty broken.  It does not adheer to the [Promises/A+](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec/) specification used by the vast majority of other promise implementations.  Promises/A+ is extremely well thought out and is the result of lots of hard work and experimenation.  jQuery's deviation from this specificaiton can often make it significantly harder to use.

If you were to use an alternative implementation (e.g. [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or my own [promise](https://github.com/then/promise)) you could do:

```
Q($.ajax({
    url: 'myurl' + obj.id,
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}));
```

or

```
var Promise = require('promise');
Promise.from($.ajax({
    url: 'myurl' + obj.id,
    dataType: 'jsonp'
}));
```

to get a real Promises/A+ promise from a jQuery one.

Comment: Forbes, since when did `.done()` return undefined? Maybe you would like to reconsider your opening paragraph.

Comment: Forbes, not "should", "does" guaranteed, every time. If you want to be taken seriously as a member of the "jQuery promises are broken" brigade, then you will need to sell yourself as an informed critic.

Comment: I'm rusty, and I prefer not to focus on "jQuery is broken" and instead to focus on "Q et al. are awesome".  The OPs problems are clearly coming largely from the design mistakes in jQuery's promise implementation, hence my suggestion that they use `.then` in place of `.done` when appropriate and that they consider alternative promise implementations which have more consistent/simpler APIs (and comply with standards).

Comment: There's some misleading info here: `done` is not part of the Promises/A+ spec, and jQuery's `then` looks like it's compliant.  Is the criticism of jQuery's implementation (still) valid?

Comment: Also, jQueries `done` does not silence error messages.  So, as far as I can tell, the only difference is that jQueries `done` is chainable, which is, if anything, a mild advantage (and in any case, usually you want `then`, not `done`).

Comment: jQuery's `then` method has the correct method signature, but does not have anything like the correct behavior.  It is no where near compliant.  I don't know much about jQuery's `done` but it differs from most other implementations.  There is, however, no formal spec for `done` yet, so it's not necessarily fair to describe it as broken. I had no intention to suggest that `done` was part of any formal spec (although I strongly believe it should be added).  `done` is, however, implemented by most popular Promise implementations.

Answer (score 1):

`$.when(everything)...` is totally legal but unnecessary as `$.when()` is a "promise combiner", designed to accept multiple promise parameters.

As `everything` is already a promise, returned by the `$.when.apply(...).done(...)` chain, it's probably clearer name it as follows :

```
var everything_promise = $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {..});
```

Further promise methods can be called as follows :

```
everything_promise.done(function() {..}).fail(function() {..});
```

Depending on circumstances, you might alternatively choose to use `.then()`.

```
everything_promise.then(function() {..}, function() {..});
```

Regarding timing, both your original `$.when(everything)...` form and my `everything_promise.done(...)` form :

- will fire immediately if the promise is already resolved or rejected
- may fire at some point in the future when the promise becomes resolved or rejected

Comment: Thank you very much for all of these answers and comments. My mind is much clearer now and I am considering to use one of the mentioned libraries. Unfortunately the real answer to my question is in the comments of the question and it came from Kevin B. I was trying to return out of an asynchronous callback and of course now I understand that is not allowed by design and I am rewriting the whole procedure taking into account all of your considerations.